# Insert dates between startdate and enddate in SQL (ssms)

Tags: sql, date, ssms

Hi I need to insert all dates between `startdate` and `enddate` of a `casenumber` is SQL (ssms). So instead of having one row per `casenumber` the `casenumber` will have a row for each day. So if there is 10 days between the case started and ended it will have 10 rows. If the case has not been ended it will have a `NULL` in the original table but should be replaced with `getdate`. See attach image.

[image of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W1bB.png)

Answer (score 0):

This achieves your picture:

**Test Data Setup**

```
create table #test (CaseNumber int, StartDate date, Enddate date)
insert into #test (CaseNumber, StartDate, Enddate)
values(1,'2019-09-18','2019-09-24'),(2,'2019-09-23',NULL)
```

**The Code**

```
;with dt_seq as (
    select t.CaseNumber, t.StartDate, isnull(t.Enddate,cast (getdate() as date)) EndDate, t.StartDate [Date]
    from #test t
    union all
    select z.CaseNumber, z.StartDate, z.EndDate, case when z.[Date] < z.EndDate then dateadd(day,1,z.[Date]) else z.EndDate end [Date]
    from dt_seq z
    where z.[Date] <= dateadd(day,-1,z.EndDate)
    )
select c.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by c.CaseNumber order by c.[Date]) [Duration]
from dt_seq c
 order by c.CaseNumber, c.[Date]
 option ( MaxRecursion 0 )
```

**Reuslts**

[image]